# SQL Update procedure in Delphi not updating

Tags: delphi, sql-update

I have been struggling to get this procedure to work for the past 5 hours. I have tried trimming it down till a point where it works and building on that, but still no go. I would really appreciate some help, as I have to present this project, in a working state, tomorrow morning.

I have trimmed my code (as it is very long), but the problem is still evident.

```
sqlCon.Connected := true;  //TSQLConnection
sqlUsers.Active := true;  //TSQLTable
sqlGames.Active := true;  //TSQLTable
sqlPredictions.Active := true;  //TSQLTable

sqlUsers.First;

//All following variables are integers.

rugbyChampionshipScore := 10;
rugbyChampionshipGamesPredicted:= 10;
rugbyChampionshipGamesCorrect:= 10;
rugbyChampionshipGamesAlmost:= 10;
rugbyChampionshipGamesWrong:= 10;
currieCupScore := 10;
currieCupGamesPredicted := 10;
currieCupGamesCorrect := 10;
currieCupGamesAlmost := 10;
currieCupGamesWrong := 10;

sqlQueryUpdate.Close;  //TSQLQuery

sqlQueryUpdate.CommandText := 'UPDATE users SET overallScore=:parScore, overallGamesPredicted=:parGamesPredicted, overallGamesCorrect=:parGamesCorrect, overallGamesAlmost=:parGamesAlmost, overallGamesWrong=:parGamesWrong, overallAccuracy=:parAccuracy WHERE username=:parUsername';
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.Clear;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parUsername', ptUnknown).AsString := sqlUsers.FieldByName('username').AsString;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parScore', ptUnknown).AsInteger := Round((rugbyChampionshipScore + currieCupScore) / (rugbyChampionshipGamesPredicted + currieCupGamesPredicted));
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parGamesPredicted', ptUnknown).AsInteger := rugbyChampionshipGamesPredicted + currieCupGamesPredicted;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parGamesCorrect', ptUnknown).AsInteger := rugbyChampionshipGamesCorrect + currieCupGamesCorrect;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parGamesAlmost', ptUnknown).AsInteger := rugbyChampionshipGamesAlmost + currieCupGamesAlmost;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parGamesWrong', ptUnknown).AsInteger := rugbyChampionshipGamesWrong + currieCupGamesWrong;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parAccuracy', ptUnknown).AsInteger := Round(100 / (rugbyChampionshipGamesPredicted + currieCupGamesPredicted)*(rugbyChampionshipGamesCorrect + currieCupGamesCorrect) + ((rugbyChampionshipGamesAlmost + currieCupGamesAlmost)/2));

sqlQueryUpdate.ExecSQL();
sqlQueryUpdate.Close;

sqlUsers.Active := false;
sqlGames.Active := false;
sqlPredictions.Active := false;
```

Comment: What is the `sqlQueryUpdate` ? Does it have `CommandType` set to `ctQuery` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. `sqlQueryUpdate` is a `TSQLQuery` component, and I cannot find a `CommandType` property.

Comment: Well, at first use [`SQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.SQL) property instead of `CommandText` to specify the query.

Comment: OK I did that, but it's still not working :( EDIT: Just to be clear, I added a `sqlQueryUpdate.SQL.Clear;` and below that (replacing the CommandText part) `sqlQueryUpdate.SQL.Add('UPDATE users SET overallScore=:parScore, overallGamesPredicted=:parGamesPredicted, overallGamesCorrect=:parGamesCorrect, overallGamesAlmost=:parGamesAlmost, overallGamesWrong=:parGamesWrong, overallAccuracy=:parAccuracy WHERE username=:parUsername');`

Comment: Why do you create those params? They should automagically appear by changing SQL or setting CommandText while ParamCheck is true. Normally you only have to set the values.

Comment: BTW, how do you check for the query fail?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I explicitly declared the params, as I thought it was required. And I have put this code in a `try..except` block, which gives me visual feedback on an error.

Comment: Is an exception thrown?  You should have a try..except and see if you get a helpful message, like an unknown column, bad type, SQL syntax error, etc.. Also, you say you've tried to narrow it down, but you haven't.  You've got 7 parameters in your query, when ONE is enough to see if you've got the parameter syntax correct.  Get it working with ONE value being updated to a hardcoded value. If that works, then try one parameter. If that works, add the other parameters.  i.e. start simple, build up, and as you go, you'll find the failure.

Comment: @ChrisThornton: Thanks, I will try that now. While I am debugging, the exception is still thrown even if it is in a `try..except` block. I then use that error message to debug the code. If this is the wrong way to go about it, please correct me. EDIT: Oh and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Is the user modifying the record? The selected record?

Answer (score -1):

This is odd. I have followed the advice of everyone who commented, and I found out that the order in which I create my params influence the query.

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
sqlCon.Connected := true;
sqlUsers.Active := true;
sqlGames.Active := true;
sqlPredictions.Active := true;

sqlUsers.First;

sqlQueryUpdate.Close;

sqlQueryUpdate.SQL.Clear;
sqlQueryUpdate.SQL.Add('UPDATE users SET overallScore=:parScore WHERE username=:parUsername');
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.Clear;

sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parUsername', ptUnknown).AsString := sqlUsers.FieldByName('username').AsString;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parScore', ptUnknown).AsInteger := 200;


sqlQueryUpdate.ExecSQL();
sqlQueryUpdate.Close;
```

**Code that works:**

```
...
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parScore', ptUnknown).AsInteger := 200;
sqlQueryUpdate.Params.CreateParam(ftUnknown, 'parUsername', ptUnknown).AsString := sqlUsers.FieldByName('username').AsString;
...
```

So simply swapping those 2 lines makes it work? Can anyone tell me why? I am curious...

Comment: As @Uwe already mentioned, you don't need to create those params manually. Let the query object do that hard work for you. You just access them like `sqlQueryUpdate.ParamByName('parScore').AsInteger := ...`, or, if you prefer faster way and know the order how the parameters appear in the query, then you can use indexed access like `sqlQueryUpdate.Params[0].AsInteger := ...`.

Comment: @TLama Thanks for the recommendation. I will be using the latter method from now.

Comment: This should have been an update to the question, not an answer.